# Cannot include gsl on m1 mac

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, apple-m1, gsl

Although, I have installed GSL Library with `homebrew` successfully.

```
brew info gsl
==> gsl: stable 2.7.1 (bottled)
Numerical library for C and C++
https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1 (290 files, 9.8MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2022-10-12 at 19:30:40
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/gsl.rb
License: GPL-3.0-or-later
==> Analytics
install: 3,814 (30 days), 10,911 (90 days), 50,876 (365 days)
install-on-request: 1,590 (30 days), 4,514 (90 days), 22,602 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

Now I want to run this simple program in **VSCode** to make sure the library works as expected.I have added the `includePath` in the `c_cpp_properties.json` it cannot include the `*.h` correctly

**My script**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>

int
main (void)
{
  double x = 5.0;
  double y = gsl_sf_bessel_J0 (x);
  printf ("J0(%g) = %.18e\n", x, y);
  return 0;
}
```

**c_cpp_properties.json**

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

**launch.json**

```
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": []
}
```

I receive the error message `fatal error: 'gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h' file not found`

Answer (score 2):

I managed to compile it from the command line with the following commands:

```
gcc -Wall -I/opt/homebrew/include -c try.c
gcc -L/opt/homebrew/lib try.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

Further in VSCode the task.json must be modified accordingly to link the library to the include path.

**task.json**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-I/opt/homebrew/include",
                "-L/opt/homebrew/lib",
                "-lgsl",
                "-lgslcblas",
                "-lm"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

**c_cpp_properties.json**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/opt/homebrew/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

EDIT: c_cpp_properties.json is not actually relevant. Arguments of task.json matters.